# How to set memory.limit in RStudio on Windows Vista at startup?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am running RStudio 0.92.38 on Windows Vista x64. I have hard time to increase the memory limit to what I have (12GB) by using `memory.limit`, such as `memory.limit(size=12000)` for ~ 12 GB. I always get error:

> memory.limit()
>   [1] 3904
>   memory.limit(size=12000)
>   [1] 3904
>   Warning message:
>   In memory.size(size) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored

Some related info:

> version
>                  _
>   platform       x86_64-pc-mingw32
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32
>   system         x86_64, mingw32
>   status
>   major          2
>   minor          11.1
>   year           2010
>   month          05
>   day            31
>   svn rev        52157
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 2.11.1 (2010-05-31)

When I issued the same `memory.limit()` from Rgui.exe, I got:

> memory.limit()
>   [1] 12270

It seems RStudio is limiting the memory usage.

Any help?

Thanks.
SP

Comment: Hi, if you wouldn't mind posting this at the [RStudio support forum](http://support.rstudio.org) instead, that would make it a lot easier for us to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug that will be fixed in v0.93 of RStudio. Thanks.