# How To Limit the Amount of RAM RServer/RSession Uses on Windows

Tags: r, rserve

I need to limit the amount of RAM RServer/RSession uses on our Windows 2012 server.

I am a system admin who has two users running R Studio on our Server. Each R Studio spawns one or more `RSession.exe` processes. Sometimes one of the `RSession.exe` processes takes up too much RAM. Yesterday, it grew to about 60GB, forcing almost everything else running to a halt. (We have 72 GB available, but 48 GB of that is allocated to SQL Server.) I need to make sure that using R doesn’t bring down my server or affect other applications running on it.

Info:

```
   sessionInfo()
   R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
   Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)
```

As suggested in some forums, I tried adding `--max-mem-size=4000M` to the shortcut they use to start R. This works with `RGUI.exe`, but doesn’t work with `RStudio.exe`. When I run `memory.limit()` from `RGui`, it return `4000`, as expected. When I run `memory.limit()` from `RStudio`,  it returns `71999`, regardless of the start parameters. And, in any case, I’m not certain this is the right place to set limits. Would a command line switch like this for `RStudio` affect `RSession` processes it spawns?

I also tried running  `memory.limit(4000)` from within `RStudio`, but got the following message:

```
“Warning message: In memory.limit(4000) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored”
```

I’ve also read something about setting memory limits in user profiles, but all of the instructions for doing so are Unix oriented and refer to files and directories that don’t exist on our Windows server. (Sorry, I’m not an R person, just a poor sysadmin trying to keep his server alive…)

One post noted that “Just to let you know, support.rstudio.com on 2014/06/10: "We've got it on our list of things to investigate and hope to have a solution soon" ([How to set memory limit in RStudio (desktop version)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950132/how-to-set-memory-limit-in-rstudio-desktop-version)). Is this a bug? If so, what work-arounds are there? If not, how can I limit RSession memory usage so it doesn’t bring down my server?

Thank You,
Robbie