# foreach %dopar% long vectors not supported yet: memory.c:3782

Tags: r, multiprocessing, snow

I am trying to use `snow` to perform some multiprocessing using this code:

```
cl <- makeCluster(32)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

result <-
    foreach(
      i = 1:iterations,
    ) %dopar%
    {
      current_value <- pull(nearby_genes[i,1])
      
      # DO ANALYSIS FOR CURRENT VALUE

}
```

This results in the following error:
`mpi.send(x = serialize(obj, NULL), type = 4, dest = dest, tag = tag, : long vectors not supported yet: memory.c:3782`. I did some research and found out that it has something to do with memory issues. One of the dataframes that I am using inside the `foreach` loop is >5million rows long and has 14 columns so I think it occupies more than 2GB of RAM which triggers the error.

Am I right in this assumption and does anyone have an idea how to circumvent this problem?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If it's a memory Problem, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950132/how-to-set-memory-limit-in-rstudio-desktop-version#54806324

Comment: I don't think any of these relate to my problem. I think that `snow` doesn't accept if objects are bigger than 2GB to be used inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Seems strange that something made for parallel processing doesn't accept large datasets. You could look into multidplyr, I've used that with fairly large data (certainly over 2 GB per cluster) without any problems.

Comment: Can `multidplyr`  also be used to parallize for loops? I am not using any dplyr operations inside my for loop.