# Memory limit in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I tried to decrease and give some limit to R studio but it didn't work.
I've read [this article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200663736-Set-memory-limit-in-preferences-64-bit-Windows-) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328480/how-to-set-memory-limit-in-rstudio-on-windows-vista-at-startup).

[image]

My computer is running Windows 8 64 Bit with RAM 8 GB. I just want to give memory limit to R Studio only 4 GB.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to just use:

```
memory.limit()
[1] 8157
memory.limit(size=4000)
```

If you are running a server version of RStudio, it will be a bit different. You will have to change the file `/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf` and add `rsession-memory-limit-mb=4000` to it.

If you do find that RStudio is resetting the memory limit with every new instance, you could try and add `memory.limit(size=4000)` to your `.Rprofile` file that sets your with every start